# Jsoup unable to connect (sometimes)

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm using jsoup in a project, but I find that sometimes, the following instruction is unable to obtain the document:

```
 Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).get();
```

The strange thing is that with the browser I can open the url in less then 2 seconds, while jsoup has this problem. Another strange thing is that most of the time, jsoup works well.

What's wrong?

Comment: is it always the same URL that fails?

Comment: @luksch, yes, but I find that the problem is usually on the smartphone: in the genymotion emulator, all works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites look at the user-agent string of the connecting browser to decide what content to deliver. It may be that the user-agent Jsoup sends along is not clear enough. So my suggestions would be to play with the user-agent like this:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
   .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
   .timeout(30000)
   .get();
```

Another possibility would be that the webserver needs some cookies to be set correctly. You need to look at the exact traffic between a browser and the website to find out more. (Use the Network tab in the browser development mode)

Without the URL that gives you the problems I fear this is all advice I can offer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already trying with userAgent and seems to improve performances.

Comment: so is your problem solved? if yes, please consider accepting the answer and/or up-voting it, if it helped. If your question is not solved, please refine it and state the exact errors and URL.